# How to view errors being generated by Azure Compute Emulator

Tags: azure, azure-compute-emulator

I have a WCF service solution which contains the WCF service and a Azure Cloud Service project.

When running the cloud service project in the Azure Compute Emulator (version 2.5 on my PC), all I see in the output for each role is

> [fabric] Role state Busy
>
> [fabric] Role state Aborted

I've tweaked the logging level in Compute Emulator to log `Warning`, or `Error` and even tried `Critical`, but no more detailed messages are displayed. I have been Googling to see if there are any event log entries, or log files on disk, that I can view to find out why the cloud service is not working, but to no avail.

What can I do to find out more about what is causing the Cloud Service role to abort and and retry?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Diagnostics logs are not collected in the Azure compute emulator** – For projects that target the Azure SDK version 2.5, the Azure compute emulator no longer supports the collection of diagnostics logs, including performance counters, infrastructure logs, IIS logs, and event logs. In addition, logs are no longer stored in Azure storage or development storage. You can continue to view application logs in the Visual Studio Output window or the compute emulator. This only affects projects that target Azure SDK version 2.5; projects that continue to target Azure SDK 2.4 are not affected.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn873976.aspx

Comment: That's nice of Microsoft to do that. WTF?

Comment: My thoughts exactly! Unless you have a need for ETW logs, I would suggest going back to SDK 2.4.

Comment: Somehow, Azure SDK 2.5 is installed on my PC. We are targeting Azure SDK 2.4 on the team, so how v2.5 got installed on mine is mystery.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it turned out to be a startup task defined in `ServiceDefinition.csdef` that was the problem. After I removed the `<Task>` my service ran fine in Compute Emulator.